# building ios 10 app using xcode 8 and ibm mobile first platform 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios10, xcode8

I am building a ios 10 app using xcode 8 and ibm mobile first 7.1. However the app can not connect to the mfp server.

Here is the error code:

```
Client registration failed with error: {"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"Invalid response when registering application","invocationContext":null}
2016-09-21 10:02:37.753286 [ERROR] [NONE] [/apps/services/api/**********/iphone/init] failure. state: 200, response: undefined
```

I am under HTTP network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will not be able to communicate with the back end by using plain HTTP or older SSL/TLS protocols from iOS 9 on-wards. This feature is introduced by Apple and you can find more information about this [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/mobilefirst-platform-support-for-ios-9/#application-transport-security-ats).

If you turned off Application transport security feature and still facing this issue means then we require entire client side log and network capture between your client and server in order to debug the issue as this error occurs for multiple reasons.